# How eliminate switch in this specific example

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have controller method that get data from request and based on subject variable from request decide to call a function. (for project need I cannot use seperate controller method for each subject variable)

For now I used switch but I think it breaks Open Closed Principle (because every time new type of subject added I have to add new case to switch) and not good design, How can I refactor this code?

```
 Subject subject = ... //(type of enum)
 JSONObject data = request.getData("data");

switch(subject) {

    case SEND_VERIFY:
       send_foo1(data.getString("foo1_1"), data.getString("foo1_2"));
       break;

    case do_foo2:
       foo2(data.getInt("foo2_b"), data.getInt("foo2_cc"));
       break;

    case do_foo3:
       do_foo3_for(data.getString("foo3"));
       break;

    // some more cases

 }
```

Comment: *I think it breaks Open Closed Principle* and why do you think ?

Comment: I'd remove the `:`(s) before the values in your `case`(s).

Comment: @Ravi I edit post add add reason

Comment: [Replace Conditional Logic with Strategy](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398607&seqNum=2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I am not sure about which OO principle this snippet violates, there is indeed a more roust way to achieve the logic: tie the processing for each enum value to the enum class.

You will need to generalize the processing into an interface:

```
public interface SubjectProcessor
{
   void process(JSONObject data);
}
```

and create concrete implementations for each enum value:

```
public class SendVerifySubjectProcessor implements SubjectProcessor
{
   @Override
   public void process(JSONObject data) {
     String foo1 = data.getString("foo1_1");
     String foo2 = data.getString("foo1_2");
     ...
   }
}
```

once you have that class hierarchy tree, you can associate each enum value to a concrete processor

```
public enum Subject
{
   SEND_VERIFY(new SendVerifySubjectProcessor()),
   do_foo2(new Foo2SubjectProcessor()),
   ...
   private SubjectProcessor processor

   Subject(SubjectProcessor processor) {
     this.processor = processor;
   }

   public void process(JSONObject data) {
     this.processor.process(data);
   }
}
```

This eliminates the need for the switch statement in the controller:

```
 Subject subject = ... //(type of enum)
 JSONObject data = request.getData("data");
 subject.process(data);
```

### EDIT:

Following the good comment, You can utilize the `java.util.function.Consumer` functional interface instead of the custom `SubjectProcessor` one.  You can decide whether to write concrete classes or use the lambda expr construct.

```
public class SendVerifySubjectProcessor implements Consumer<JSONObject>
{
   @Override
   public void accept(JSONObject data) {
     String foo1 = data.getString("foo1_1");
     String foo2 = data.getString("foo1_2");
     ...
   }
}
```

OR

```
public enum Subject
{
   SEND_VERIFY(data -> {
     String foo1 = data.getString("foo1_1");
     String foo2 = data.getString("foo1_2");
     ...
   }),

   ...
   private Consumer<Subject> processor

   Subject(Consumer<Subject> processor) {
     this.processor = processor;
   }

   public void process(JSONObject data) {
     this.processor.accept(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI. Java-8 has made these tasks bit more simple, we no need to create these functional classes, we can take one coming out of the box may be `java.util.function.Consumer`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, added this option in edited answer

Answer (score 4):

```
// SubjectsMapping.java
Map<Subject, Consumer<JSONObject>> tasks = new HashMap<>();
tasks.put(SEND_VERIFY, 
    data -> send_foo1(data.getString("foo1_1"), data.getString("foo1_2")));
tasks.put(do_foo2, 
    data -> foo2(data.getInt("foo2_b"), data.getInt("foo2_cc")));
tasks.put(do_foo3, data -> do_foo3_for(data.getString("foo3")));


// In your controller class where currently `switch` code written
if (tasks.containsKey(subject)) {
    tasks.get(subject).accept(data);
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No suitable task");
}
```

You can maintain `Map<Subject, Consumer<JSONObject>> tasks` configuration in separate class rather than mixing with `if (tasks.containsKey(subject))` code. When you need another feature you can configure one entry in this map.

Comment: Map key is `Subject` not as sepcified

Comment: `SEND_VERIFY` can be a `Subject` instance or we use enum the way you have mentioned in your example. I was just showing we may need to maintain mapping like this.

Answer (score 2):

Answers of others seems to be great, as an addition I would suggest using `EnumMap` for storing enums as keys as it might be more efficient than the standard `Map`. I think it's also worth mentioning that the **Strategy Pattern** is used here to achieve calling specific actions for each key from `Map` without the need of building long switch statements.